# limitation of zookeeper's znode version stat?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

In [zookeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/), a znode has a monotonic version number that changes every time the node is modified. This is used to implement atomic updates, where a set operation will fail if the version number is not exactly the one specified.

However, deleting a znode then re-creating it resets its version number.
Imagine this scenario, where a process is trying to atomically increment a value "/x":

1. Process A reads a znode "/x". It has value "1" and version 1.
2. Process B deletes "/x"
3. Process C creates "/x" and sets the value to "0". The version number is now 0.
4. Process D updates "/x" and sets the value to "100". The version number is now 1.
5. Process A adds 1 to its read copy of "/x", getting "2". Process A attempts to set "/x" to "2" with version = 1
6. The write succeeds, as the version number is correct.

Now an attempt to increment a number has actually caused it to drop by 98!
Note that this isn't theoretical, I've created a test case that demonstrates this situation.

So my question is:

How do you correctly implement an atomic update in zookeeper under conditions where a node may be deleted and re-created at any time? Or is this a fundamental limitation of the system, and it can only be correct when znode paths are never re-used?